# Adding another column to a CSV file w/ python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-2.x

I am looking to add another column to a CSV file w/ python.

file1 is Date.csv has format

```
ID, Date
0,"Jan 22, 2016"
1,"Jan 21, 2016"
2,"Jan 20, 2016"
3,"Jan 19, 2016"
```

and

file2 is Price.csv

```
ID, Price
0,27.89
1,26.80
2,26.78
3,26.00
```

My desired output is (in Date.csv)

```
ID, Date
0,"Jan 22, 2016", 27.89
1, "Jan 21, 2016", 26.80
2, "Jan 20, 2016", 26.78
3, "Jan 19, 2016", 26.00
```

but what I'm returning is the price repeating

```
0,27.89,27.89
1,26.80,26.80
2,26.78,26.78
3,26.00,26.00
```

My program is as follows

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Price.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Date.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(row[1])
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Appreciate some guidance, cheers

Comment: you have to read from both files, connect rows and write to new file. And  at the end you can rename new file to `Date.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just write a single column into an existing file. Best option is create a new file. If the data is in order for both files then you can simply zip them up and write the updated dictionary out:

```
with open('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Date.csv') as file1, \
     open('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Price.csv') as file2, \
     open('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Output.csv', 'w') as output:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(file2)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, ['ID', 'Date', 'Price'])
    writer.writeheader()  # Optional if you want the header

    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        row1.update(row2)
        writer.writerow(row1)
```

Pandas is also a another option:

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', index_col='ID')
file2 = pd.read_csv('Price.csv', index_col='ID')
pd.concat([file1,file2], axis=1).to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Output:

```
ID,Date,Price
0,"Jan 22, 2016",27.89
1,"Jan 21, 2016",26.80
2,"Jan 20, 2016",26.78
3,"Jan 19, 2016",26.00
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I [partially] resolved this another way with

import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Date.csv")
file2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Price.csv")
output = pd.concat([file1,file2], axis=1)
output.to_csv("All.csv")

and then delete the additional column.

Comment: You can avoid deleting additional columns in pandas if you set the `index_col` - see update

Answer (score 3):

You need 3 files at the same time, and append only needed column from second file

```
import csv

date_reader = csv.reader(open('Date.csv', 'rb'))
price_reader = csv.reader(open('Price.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open('NewData.csv', 'wb'))
for date_row in date_reader:
    price_row = price_reader.next()
    writer.writerow(date_row + [price_row[1]])
```

And the output:

```
ID, Date, Price
0,"Jan 22, 2016",27.89
1,"Jan 21, 2016",26.80
2,"Jan 20, 2016",26.78
3,"Jan 19, 2016",26.00
```

Comment: You could avoid the `.next()` call with `zip`, e.g. `for date_row, price_row in zip(date_reader, price_reader):`. BTW `.next()` does not work in Py3, use `next(price_reader)`

Comment: i just changed his code a little bit, so it does what it supposed to

Comment: does using 'rb' and 'wb' as opposed to 'r' and 'w' make a difference?

Comment: you can read here difference between using r or rb - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files