# Adding another column to an output

Tags: python, csv

Thank you so very much for your time. So sorry to bother you with my programming noobiness, but I've spent much of the past two days testing and searching for a method to solve my problem and I seem to be simply lacking the context to land on what I believe should be a simple solution. A friend who is now out of town wrote a short python script for me (copied below) that inputs any number of .csv files with different but overlapping indices and values for those indices. The script then requests selection of the greatest value for each index between that of all the input files and creates a compilation .csv with all indices and the greatest value for each. I'd like to add a third column to that output .csv that displays the source filename for each highest value. I think my problem is different from this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005798/adding-another-column-to-a-csv-file-w-python because there is not a one-to-one correlation between indices and filename information - the desired filename output is dependent instead on the max value. It doesn't matter to me whether the source of the filename is the filename itself or a third column manually entered into the input .csvs beforehand displaying the filename for each row, nor does it matter what filename is outputted if two files have the same value for the same index. Despite trying everything I can think of, I have not been successful in adding this output to the script. Thank you so very much!!

```
import csv
import sys
import operator
import numpy

filenames = [
    "All_Culverts_K.csv",
    "All_Culverts5817.csv",
    "All_culverts_5.2.csv",
    "All_Culverts.csv",
    "All_CulvertsCopy.csv"]

output = "All_Culverts_Run_5.11_Max_Areas3.csv"

maxAreas = [None] * 3000

for filename in filenames:
     try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
            input_table = csv.reader(csv_file)

            # Get rid of header
            header_row = next(input_table)

            row_number = 0

            # Go through all rows in the table after the header.
            for row in input_table:

                try:
                    ws_index = row[0].index('ws')

                    index = int(row[0][:ws_index])
                    value = float(row[1])



                    if (maxAreas[index] == None):
                        maxAreas[index] = value


                    else:
                        if (maxAreas[index] < value) :
                            maxAreas[index] = value

                except ValueError:
                    print "Error, missing ws on row " + str(row_number)



                row_number += 1

        csv_file.close()


   except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Could not find file '" \
            + filename \
            + "'. Bailing out."
        sys.exit(0)

# Write the maximums.
f_out = open(output, 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f_out)
csv_writer.writerow(['BarrierID', 'Area_sqkm', 'Source_file'])

row_number = 0

for area in maxAreas:
    csv_writer.writerow([str(row_number) + 'ws', area])
    row_number += 1

print "Done! View .csv in folder."

f_out.close()
```

What have I tried thus far?
- adding third column to input .csvs displaying sourcefile
- creating source_file variable
- appending source_file input to if statements
- adding source_file variable to writerow command
- tons of googling and reading some of the python docs

Comment: `csv_writer.writerow([str(row_number) + 'ws', area])` => `csv_writer.writerow([str(row_number) + 'ws', area,"some_file"])` adds a 3rd row...

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, Jean-Francois! That indeed adds the third column (yay!), but it's not dynamic - replacing "some_file" with filename, for example, simply prints the name of the last file run to all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
import csv
import sys
import operator
import numpy

filenames = [
    "All_Culverts_K.csv",
    "All_Culverts5817.csv",
    "All_culverts_5.2.csv",
    "All_Culverts.csv",
    "All_CulvertsCopy.csv"]

output = "All_Culverts_Run_5.11_Max_Areas3.csv"

maxAreas = [None] * 3000

for filename in filenames:
     try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
            input_table = csv.reader(csv_file)

            # Get rid of header
            header_row = next(input_table)

            row_number = 0

            # Go through all rows in the table after the header.
            for row in input_table:

                try:
                    ws_index = row[0].index('ws')

                    index = int(row[0][:ws_index])
                    value = float(row[1])


    ##modification nr.1: use keyword is when checking for None
                    if (maxAreas[index] is None):
    ##modification nr.2: store a tuple instead of just the value
                        maxAreas[index] = (value, filename)


                    else:
    ##modification nr.3: use the numerical value in the stored tuple by adding [0]  
                        if (maxAreas[index][0] < value) :
    ##modification nr.4: store a tuple instead of just the value    
                            maxAreas[index] = (value, filename)

                except ValueError:
                    print "Error, missing ws on row " + str(row_number)



                row_number += 1

        csv_file.close()


   except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Could not find file '" \
            + filename \
            + "'. Bailing out."
        sys.exit(0)

# Write the maximums.
f_out = open(output, 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f_out)
csv_writer.writerow(['BarrierID', 'Area_sqkm', 'Source_file'])

row_number = 0

#modification nr. 5: unpack the tuple into area and filename1 when iterating
#through maxAreas; use filename1 instead of filename to catch possible errors
for area, filename1 in maxAreas:
#modification nr.6: store the additional filename1
    csv_writer.writerow([str(row_number) + 'ws', area, filename1])
    row_number += 1

print "Done! View .csv in folder."

f_out.close()
```

The code is almost identical to your original, but in the places where you determine the maxima for each index, I store a tuple, `(maxArea, filename)`, to keep the information, in which file the maximum was found. Then in the end, I unpack these two values from `maxAreas` and add the additional row to the csv file according to the comment by [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre). I have to admit, that I have no experience with csv, so there is a chance that I get it totally wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, Thomas! I didn't know I could store a tuple there, so that's very helpful to me. Your code does indeed add a 3rd column w/ a filename to the output (yay!), but unfort. the script no longer selects the greatest areas. Instead, it now prints a tuple with the area and filename of the first file processed in the output second column, and the name of the final file processed in the third column.

Comment: Like so:    0ws (1.00738, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv 
   1ws (0.0005287, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    2ws (0.0004228, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    3ws (0.0002191, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    4ws (0.0002191, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    5ws (1.84251, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    6ws (6.84e-05, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv
    7ws (6.84e-05, 'All_Culverts_K.csv') All_CulvertsCopy.csv

Comment: When my desired output would be something like this: 0ws 1.00878 All_CulvertsCopy.csv 1ws 0.0901 All_Culverts5817.csv 2ws 1.4418 All_Culverts.csv 3ws .08995 All_Culverts.csv etc.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately, as I don't have the input files, I can't test the script myself, but I did write a little test script and the principle logic of my fix should be ok. Can you post here a sample of the final content of the `maxAreas` variable? Do you get any error messages while running the code?

Comment: Did you notice the added `[0]` in `if (maxAreas[index][0] < value)`?

Comment: Also, you need to alter the final `for` loop, `for area, filename in maxAreas:`, otherwise `filename` will always contain the last filename from the previous `for` loop, and `area` will be a tuple -- I will mark all the lines that I have altered in my example.